# Angular - component selector using ID

Tags: angular

I want to use an element ID for a component selector but it doesn't work.

Is this not allowed in Angular? If so why not?

(so a selector of `.btnAction` matches, and the button is inserted into Component 1's template, but `#btnAction` doesn't)

I'm not sure this is necessary, but here's the code through which I've confirmed that *other* CSS selectors work (like class and attribute), but ID's don't.

**Component 1**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myelement',
    template: `<div id="btnAction" class="btnAction"></div>`,
    directives: [ActionBtn]
})
```

**Component 2**

```
@Component({
    selector: '#btnAction',
    template: `<button>{{btnTitle}}</button>`
})
```

Comment: Id is explicitly not supported as component selector.

Comment: What's the reason? Or at least where can I find the documentation for what _can_ go into the selector?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you would need this?

Comment: I'm switching over from a jQuery FE background, so it's very unusual for me that the "id" selector is all of a sudden _banned_, it's a completely standard CSS selector.

Comment: It's not about standard CSS. Angular also doesn't support selectors that need to match more than one element (like with space `+` or `>`).

Answer (score 6):

yes!!!

ID selector is also supported by angular 2+.
we can use either element, class or id. below is the code which will work.

1. using id selector

`@Component({
  selector: '[id=idname]',
  templateUrl: 'template path',
  styleUrls: ['css path']
})`

2. using class selector

`@Component({
  selector: '.classname', //or '[class=classname]'
  templateUrl: 'template path',
  styleUrls: ['css path']
})`

2. using element selector

`@Component({
  selector: 'elementname'
  templateUrl: 'template path',
  styleUrls: ['css path']
})`

Comment: I think what you are using is actually an attribute selector, but it works.